# Shell script parameter substitution

Tags: shell, shell-script, variable-substitution

I have seen a line of shell script as follows:

```
local soft_upgrade=${3:-false}
```

What does this mean? I don't know what 3:-false means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's nothing about array, it's a default value in [parameter substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

If `$3` is not set, set `soft_upgrade` to `false`, otherwise, set it to `$3`

Comment: This also applies when `$3` is null, not just when it is unset.

Comment: Just "`false`", not "`-false`", `:-` is the specific parameter expansion operation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article, for me it was really useful:

[Variable Mangling in Bash with String Operators](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919)